# How to get the first integer from all lines that match a pattern?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a file and I only want to find lines that have "here". In each of these lines there are multiple string and integer values (see example below). I only want the first integer of each line that matches the pattern.

I have created a solution that uses a bash script, but is there a simpler method I am missing. I was hoping something like `grep -w here -Eo [0-9] file` would work. However when I try that it expects anything that comes after "here" to be the file.

```
STEP 1 STAGE 1 here other info
foo
bar
STEP 2 STAGE 1 here other info
more
foo
bar
STEP 3 STAGE 1 here other info
```

For this file the desired output would be

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simpler `awk` should work for you:

```bash
awk '/ here / {sub(/^[^0-9]+/, ""); print $1+0}' file

1
2
3
```

Answer (score 3):

`grep` is not the right command for this. I'd use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/ here /s/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p' file
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that this will output a blank line if there is a line containing `here` and no numbers. Perhaps change the `*` to `+` within the back reference?

Comment: @potong That's correct but it isn't clear what the expected output is supposed to be in this case (that is, when a line containing `here` but missing a digit is encountered). Printing out an empty line could be used to signal an unexpected line, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Another variant with `gnu-grep` using  `-P` for Perl-compatible regular expressions if supported:

```
grep -oP "^\D*\K\d+(?=.*\bhere\b)" file
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\D*` Match optional non digits
- `\K` Forget what is matched do far
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?=.*\bhere\b)` Positive lookahead, assert `here` to the right

Output

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk` you could try following `awk` code. Written and tested with your shown samples.

```
awk '
match($0,/(^|[[:space:]]+)([0-9]+)[[:space:]]+.*here /,arr){
  print arr[2]
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** In GNU `awk` first searching string `here` keyword AND then using `match` function of GNU `awk` where using `(^|[[:space:]]+)([0-9]+)[[:space:]]+.*here`  regex which creates 2 capturing Groups and stores their values into an array named `arr` with index of 1,2 respectively. If all these conditions are verified then printing the 2nd element of that array which is required value(integer of line).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> gawk 'sub(__,_, $!(NF=NF)) * NF' FS='^[^0-9]*' __='([^0-9].*)?$' OFS=
> ```

- or

> ```
> mawk -F'^[^0-9]*' '$!NF = int($(_*(NF=NF)))'
> ```

```
1
2
3
```